# Java regex to strip out XML tags is not working

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am trying to remove any XML tags from a Java string. The way I see it, something is an XML tag if it follows one or both of the following forms:

- `<*>*<*/*>`, such as `<fizz>buzz< /fizz>`; or
- `<*/*>`, such as `< fizz />`

My regex is simple:

```
String tagful = "Hello <fizz>buzz</fizz>Regexes!";
String tagless = tagful.replaceAll("<*>*<*/*>", "");
tagless = tagless.replaceAll("<*/*>", "");
System.err.println("TAGLESS:\n\t" + tagless);
```

When I run this I get `Hello <fizzbuzz</fizzRegexes!` as the output, whereas (if my XML-stripping code was correct), I should be getting `Hello Regexes!`. Where am I going astray?

**Please note**: I do not want to use any existing libraries; I am looking for a pure Java regex solution here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't parse XML using regular expressions.  _Why_ are you opposed to using a proper parser for this?

Comment: "*" is not a wildcard in Java regex (or most regex for that matter).  It is a "zero-or-more" quantifier, and it is being applied to whatever precedes it.  The single character wildcard regex expression is the "." (dot or period).

Comment: [Stripping tag (removing only the tags)] and [removing the tag and all its content inside] are different. I don't know what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `*` into `.*?`. Try with `"<.*?>.*?</.*?>"` and `"<.*?/>"`. 
Or just  `"<.*?>.*?</.*?>|<.*?/>"`

- `*` means that element before it can appear 0 or more times.
- `.` means "anything beside new line mark".

So `<.*>` will accept anything between `<` and `>`.

But in this form `.*` is greedy and in String such as `"<abc>def<ghi>"` will match `"abc>def<ghi"` part.

To make it match minimal set we need to use `?` after `*`.

Comment: @khachik Search for "reluctant quantifier"

Comment: Bingo bango bongo! You get the green check in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you want something like this instead - it will replace any tag ( i.e. '< >') regardless of the tag's attributes or chevron contents whatever you want to call it

```
String tagful = "Hello <fizz>buzz</fizz>Regexes!";
String tagless = tagful.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
//tagless = tagless.replaceAll("<*/*>", "");
System.err.println("TAGLESS:\n\t" + tagless);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tucker (+1) - but your solution prints out `Hello buzzRegexes!`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too..

```
String tagful = "Hello <fizz>buzz</fizz>Regexes!";
String tagless = tagful.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
System.out.println("TAGLESS:\n\t" + tagless);
```